# What are you doing when you say "ok"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If someone gives you a notification, like you have to do something, or you have to go out and get some thing, and you say "ok". What are you doing? Would 'acknowledge' be the proper word to describe your action?

Comment: [acknowledging, accepting, agreeing, defending, endorsing, recognizing, supporting, acceding, acquiescing, allowing, approving, certifying, granting, owning, ratifying, upholding,...](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/acknowledge) There are lots of possibilities, some of which may be more or less appropriate in any given context.

Comment: Sometimes 'ok' a simple acknowledgment, sometimes it is an affirmative. You should edit this question, give a situation and a sentence and the 'ok' response, then we'll be better able to judge what is meant and what the appropriate words to use to describe the situation.

Comment: You are stating "oll korrect" like an old time newsy. 
http://m.mentalfloss.com/article.php?id=50042

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...and you say "ok". What are you doing?

Well, without explaining yourself further, only you know what you are doing.

OK can mean, "I heard you" (an [acknowledgement](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/acknowledge?s=t): to show or express recognition or realization) or "I'll get right on it" ([agreement](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/agree): to give consent; assent).

OK can indicate a number of other things as well. It can even indicate disagreement or ridicule depending on how it's said.

Comment: Ok, I meant it in the sense "I heard you". Clear Explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Acknowledge" is insufficient. Because as a response to a request "okay" includes "I accept" or "I approve", "agreed" or "will do" would be better. (Of course, "okay" as affirmation or qualitative commentary could be replaced with "satisfactory", "adequate", sufficient", or "palpable". It is not so positive as many English students believe.)